# Spring-Boot Async Restcall Timeout Handling

Tags: rest, exception, asynchronous, timeout, spring-boot

I need help again, when I got that project with spring-xml it worked, but I don't know how I can register a CallableProcessingInterceptor, so that it throws an exception after timeout.

I am using Spring-Boot 1.10, One Client-Application calls RestApplication. When Response Of RestApplication takes too long, client throws timeout in background, but in browser nothing happend.

I got a class called `TimeoutCallableProcessingInterceptor` already, what it worked before when using XML-Config.

```
public class TimeoutCallableProcessingInterceptor extends CallableProcessingInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public <T> Object handleTimeout(final NativeWebRequest request, final Callable<T> task) throws Exception {
    throw new IllegalStateException("[" + task.getClass().getName() + "] timed out");
}
```

}

====

WebMvcConfig

```
// Themeleaf and ApacheTiles Configs

...


@Bean
public TimeoutCallableProcessingInterceptor timeoutInterceptor() {
    return new TimeoutCallableProcessingInterceptor();
}
```

How and where can I register that Interceptor using JAVACONFIG.

If you need more information, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I got solution:

First extends your Config-Class with  `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`
Then overwrite the method `configureAsyncSupport`:

```
@Value("${server.session-timeout}") private Long sessionTimeOut;

@Override
public void configureAsyncSupport(final AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setDefaultTimeout(sessionTimeOut * 1000L);
    configurer.registerCallableInterceptors(timeoutInterceptor());
}

@Bean
public TimeoutCallableProcessingInterceptor timeoutInterceptor() {
    return new TimeoutCallableProcessingInterceptor();
}
```

Comment: Should also be possible via "standard" config options (i.e. `server.session.timeout` and/or `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` in normal `applications.properties | yml`).  [official docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: @demaniak Have you tested this? I'm having troubles to set the `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout`.